# MongoDB how select like : SELECT _id, size.h from inventory WHERE status = "A"

Tags: mongodb

**MongoDB how select like : SELECT _id, size.h from inventory WHERE status = "A"**

```sh
db.inventory.insertMany( [
  { item: "journal", status: "A", size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 } ] },
  { item: "notebook", status: "A",  size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
  { item: "paper", status: "D", size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 } ] },
  { item: "planner", status: "D", size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: "cm" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 } ] },
  { item: "postcard", status: "A", size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
]);
```

select:

```sql
db.inventory.find( { status: "A" }, { item: 1, status: 1, _id: 0 } )

The operation corresponds to the following SQL statement:

SELECT item, status from inventory WHERE status = "A"
```

now  i need  select like

```sql
SELECT item, status,size.h from inventory WHERE status = "A"
```

i need the value only it

```cs
size.h

SQL like :

SELECT size.h from inventory WHERE status = "A"


and  the MongoDB shell how can i do it 

????????????
```

Comment: just do same as other fields in project argument `{ item: 1, status: 1, _id: 0, 'size.h': 1}`

Comment: You can also refer: [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/sql-comparison/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.inventory.find( { status: "D" }, {  'size.h': 1,'size.w': 1} )
```

Comment: Instead of one line of code, please consider editing your answer to include an explanation on why this works.